# Sending Values to file_get_contents()

Tags: php, include

I am making a site that uses the file_get_contents to display a form. The form contains three fields and is as below. What I am trying to do is insert three values that I have generated from sql queries into this form.

Is there a way that I can send the values I have generated into the correct fields of the form?

Would I have to add some php to the top of the form that will allow it receive the values being passed from the file_get_contents function?

**Calling the functions and form**

```
            //sql functions return values based on rowID
            $updateTilte = $this->model->updateTitle();
            $updatePrice = $this->model->updatePrice();
            $updateDescription = $this->model->updateDescription();

            $rightBox = file_get_contents( "templates/update_item_form.php" );
```

**Update_item_form**

```
<h2>Update Item!</h2>
<h4>Fill in the form to update an entry.</h4>
<form action="index.php" method="post">
    <fieldset>
        <input id='action' type='hidden' name='action' value='updateItem' />
        <p>
            <label for="fTitle">Title</label> <input type="text"
                id="fTitle" name="fTitle" placeholder="title"
                maxlength="25" required />
        </p>
        <p>
            <label for="fPrice">Price</label> <input type="text"
                id="fPrice" name="fPrice" placeholder="price"
                maxlength="25" required />
        </p>
        <p>
            <label for="fDescription">Description</label> <input type="text"
                id="fDescription" name="fDescription" placeholder="description"
                maxlength="500" required />
        </p>

        <p>
        <div class="form-group">
            <div class="controls">
                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success">Submit</button>
            </div>
        </div>
        </p>
    </fieldset>
</form>
```

Comment: You already asked nearly this same question and I gave you the same type of answer Erik has given you.

Comment: ^ agreeing with @Devon's comments. don't repost when you already have an answer in the other question.

Comment: Sorry I thought this was too different from what I was asking in the last question

Comment: @patrick, I can office more advice in your original question if you need it.  Feel free to continue discussion there, I have added another comment to try to help clarify what I was stating about the controller and view.

Comment: Thanks for all the help @Devon, i have taken your advice and have changed some thing around, the answer given by Erik seems to be helping me lot with my other changes, Sorry about the repost!

Answer (score 1):

No. That's not what file_get_contents does, and it's not what it's for either. What you are looking for is [include](http://php.net/manual/en/function.include.php)

It opens the file in PHP mode, executing whatever code it finds. That means you can use the variables you declared above inside the file, and PHP will replace them with their value.

Snippets:

```
$updateTilte = $this->model->updateTitle();

include "templates/update_item_form.php";
```

Form:

```
<label for="fTitle">Title</label> <input type="text"
            id="fTitle" name="fTitle" placeholder="title"
            maxlength="25" required value="<?php echo $updateTilte; ?> />
```

Note: `include` will immediately output the html in the file. Only include the file when you're ready to output everything.

Comment: Thank you for the help, quick question with the `$updateTitle`, when I run the code i get an error saying that it is undefined?